# Cannot get URL from Vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have this iframe: `<iframe src={{videoCodes}}></iframe>`
and the following js:

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        videoCodes: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/Ok_v3b7S2_Y"
    },
    methods: {

    }
})
```

But i cannot get videoCodes from Vue and put it into the iframe url. Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not bind a dynamic value to a HTML Attribute like this. The double braces or mustache syntax is only for outputting reactive data to the page, **not to bind with an attribute**. For that, you need to use a special directive in Vue called the "v-bind". More info: [Vue.js API](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind).
After the change, the template(HTML) should look like this:

```html
<!-- ...... -->
<iframe v-bind:src="videoCodes"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 2):

When using variables as attributes of elements, you need to use `v-bind`  as this: `v-bind:src="videoCodes"` or as a shorthand `:src="videoCodes"`

Docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind attribute.

You can try:

```
<iframe v-bind:src="videoCodes"></iframe>
```